# Event or notification when a View is added to a List

Tags: development, list-view, events

Is there an event or notification or some way to execute a piece of code as soon as a new View is added to a specific List?

I need to modify this newly added View (more specifically I need to edit the created file `NewView.aspx`) to add a custom WebPart to it.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, maybe we can give you some right direction ?

Comment: The default views which are shipped with the solution are automatically modified in the Featurereceiver. I need to add a WebPart to the page (like AllItems.aspx) which does some custom actions programmatically. But when I add a new View, this WP is not added of course. I need a automatic way and not with SPD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no SharePoint event for view added. [These are the available event receivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.speventreceivertype.aspx)

Comment: And what about the created file? Like `AllItems.aspx`. Is there a hidden Document Library where these files get added? This way I could add a receiver on that list.

Comment: Looks like there is really no way to find out if a new View was added. Except checking every x minutes with a TimerJob, but that is quite ugly I'd say.